# How to remove a node from a scene imported with Assimp?

Tags: c++, assimp

I need to remove one object from the scene graph imported by Assimp and I can't.  I've tried to change aiScene.h including a method called DelNode and I can´t. How can I do it - is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.

You are not permitted to modify the scene that assimp returns to you (it is `const` for this reason).

Assimp's data structures should not be used for rendering etc. instead, you should copy their contents to your own data structures appropriate to your environment.

When designing Assimp, we explicitly designed it to be only usable for importing. It's not a scenegraph library.

[That said, if you `const_cast` the scene, add that `DelNode` method to `aiScene` and NULL the slot where the node to be removed originally had been it would work as intended, but this would be a hack].